# numpy.vstack as aggregator in pandas groupy

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
d = {'group' : [1, 1, 2, 2], 'histogram' : [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9],[10,11,12]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

[image]

The dataframe contains results of a histogram analysis. The goal is to create 2D numpy arrays per group. i.e.

for group 1, the 2D numpy array would be `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])`. The shape would be (3,2)

I tried the following:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("group").agg({'histogram':'count',
                                             'histogram':lambda x: np.vstack(x)}))
```

however I get the following error:

> Exception: Must produce aggregated value

I could of course loop over the dataframe, filter by group and use

```
np.vstack(df_filtered["histogram"])
```

but I guess there must be a more pandas friendly way. Eventually I will parse the 2D arrays into a Keras model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close what you need is convert it to list:

```
df_test = (pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("group")['histogram']
             .agg([('c', 'count'),('2d',lambda x: np.vstack(x).tolist())])))
print (df_test)
       c                         2d
group                              
1      2     [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
2      2  [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Or use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
f = lambda x: pd.DataFrame([[len(x), np.vstack(x)]], columns=['c','2d'])
df_test = df.groupby("group")['histogram'].apply(f).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df_test)
       c                         2d
group                              
1      2     [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
2      2  [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```